# Webpack cannot find any of the modules imported

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, webpack, apollo-server

I have this code:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

// import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
const ApolloServer = require("apollo-server-express");
const express = require("express");
const buildSchema = require("type-graphql");
const createConnection = require("typeorm");
const cors = require("cors");

import { UserResolvers } from "./graphql/user/UserResolver";
import { UserModel } from "./graphql/user/UserModel";
import { TodoItemModel } from "./graphql/todoItem/TodoItemModel";

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

(async () => {
  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [UserResolvers],
  });

  const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });

  const { host, port, username, password, database } = process.env;

  console.log({ host }, { port }, { username }, { password }, { database });

  app.get("/user");

  server.applyMiddleware({ app });

  await createConnection({
    type: "mysql",
    host,
    port: parseInt(port),
    username,
    password,
    database,
    entities: [UserModel, TodoItemModel],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
  })

  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log(
      ` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`
    );
  });
})();
```

And here's my webpack.config

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  mode: "development",
};
```

And I build it using:

`webpack --config webpack.config.js`

The problem is I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/apollo-server-express/dist/index.js 27:21-46
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ApolloServer' in '/home/aironside/Documents/private/todo-app-graphql/backend/node_modules/apollo-server-express/dist'
 @ ./src/index.ts 40:19-51

ERROR in ./node_modules/cors/lib/index.js 5:15-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'object-assign' in '/home/aironside/Documents/private/todo-app-graphql/backend/node_modules/cors/lib'
 @ ./src/index.ts 44:11-26

ERROR in ./node_modules/cors/lib/index.js 6:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vary' in '/home/aironside/Documents/private/todo-app-graphql/backend/node_modules/cors/lib'
 @ ./src/index.ts 44:11-26

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql-subscriptions/dist/index.js 3:22-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pubsub-engine' in '/home/aironside/Documents/private/todo-app-graphql/backend/node_modules/graphql-subscriptions/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/type-graphql/dist/index.js 11:30-62
 @ ./src/index.ts 42:18-41
```

... and other similar errors, as if I didn't have these modules installed (They are installed)

I tried `import {} from`, `import x from`, `const x = require('x')`, and `const {} = require()`. I keep getting the same error.

my `package.json` dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "apollo-server-express": "^2.21.1",
  "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
  "typeorm": "^0.2.31"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
  "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
  "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
  "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
  "concurrently": "^6.0.0",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
  "ts-loader": "^8.0.18",
  "typescript": "^4.2.3",
  "webpack": "^5.27.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
},
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you have `resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"],
  },`?

Comment: That's what `ts-loader` docs say to do.

Comment: I don't think they tell you to use only `[".ts"]` https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configuration. What you need here is more like `[ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]` which would demand webpack to resolve modules without extensions in that order. There's no `./ApolloServer.ts` in `apollo-server-express/dist`.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Would you like to add an answer?